# Accessibility, button display secondary from and the button disappear after being click

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I am working in a UI where a button will be replaced by a panel with small form that can not be closed. The button will disappear after the user clicks on it.

The problem is not about how to do it in JavaScript, The problem is about how to improve the accessibility.

I am trying to solve this problem as a button collapse, hide the button except for screen readers and manage the tabindex of this element after click to be sure no one can access again.

I create a codepen to explain the solution with a simplification of my solution, but seen to hacky for me. 
https://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/oWbZYK

HTML:

```
<div>
  <button onclick="showContent(this, 'action-box');" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="action-box">Do you want to perform an action?
  </button>
  <div id="action-box" role="region" aria-label="We will do something in this box" aria-hidden="true">
    <form action="some action">
      <label for="myinput" class="control-label sr-only">
                    Introduce a value
                </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="myinput" value="" placeholder="introduce a value">
      <input type="submit" value="send action">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function showContent(node, id) {
  $(node).attr('aria-expanded', 'true')
    .attr('tabindex','-1');
  $('#'+id).attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
}
```

Should just add aria-expanded and move the focus to the new panel? I feel this solution overcomplicated.

Comment: I think it might be helpful to decide what kind of pattern this most closely mimics. Your use of `aria-expanded` suggests a disclosure widget, but the disappearance of the control implies a modal. No matter what, you have to put focus on something after the control that had the focus disappears. With a little more detail on the pattern you are mimicking I can offer some advice.

Comment: @aardrian thanks for reply. I think this is the base of my problem. I am not sure which pattern is the good one. I will appreciate if you have a suggestion about which pattern is the best here. I was thinking in a modal as you suggest, but you should be able to close the modal and this is not the case. Anyways my solution is just a proposition, fell free to change the aria attr.

Comment: I am not writing this as an answer as I am not sure which/if any of these apply, but some patterns that have described keyboard interactions and ARIA attributes that might help narrow this down: [alert dialog](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#alertdialog), [menu button](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#menubutton), [accordion](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#accordion). Do these seem over-engineered for your needs?

Comment: I am still thinking it over while juggling the day job, FWIW.

Comment: No rush @aardrian, I implemented the solution I suggesting I just want to improve it because I don't feel this is the good one. The thing is that my problem doesn't match with alert dialog (I don't interrupt to notify nothing important) menu button (It is not a menu) or accordion. The most close is the accordion. I guess

Comment: I am leaning toward suggesting you hide the button, but do not remove it from the DOM. The `aria-expanded` has value to screen readers, so maybe you clip it visually and accept that some users will be able to close it again. I am not in a position to test how making it disabled affects how it works, but that might be an option as well.

Comment: @aardrian thanks for keep going with this. It is more or less what I did but removing the tab index. If you are a not screen reader and you are tabbing around is annoying don't see the focus.

Comment: Display the button again on focus? I think I would want to test this with users.